# contact us form not showing/displaying in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form

I need help with our contact form.

The code is there but it is not showing/displaying in our contact us webpage.

This is the link: https://www.solarwhiz.com.au/contact-us/

the script is this

```js
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-no-optimize="1">
        // <![CDATA[ 
            var ss_form = {
                'account': 'MzawMDG1MDK3BAA', 
                'formID': 'MzQ3MktLNjPSNU1KNtI1SUs0001MTTPQNTU1ME1MSTE3MzCwAAA'
            }; 
            ss_form.width = '100%'; 
            ss_form.height = '1000'; 
            ss_form.domain = 'app-3QN94BN6TM.marketingautomation.services'; // 
            ss_form.hidden = {'Company': 'Anon'}; 
            // Modify this for sending hidden variables, or overriding values // 
        ]]>
    </script>
    <br>
    <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="//koi-3QN94BN6TM.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1" 
        data-no-optimize="1">
    </script>
</p>
```

You can view the previous look of the webpage by searching through google and by viewing in cache

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. that is the only script for the form. I didn't touch the code I just wonder what's causing the issue why the contact form won't display/show?